# What Firebase mechanism to use for system logging, Fabric, Firebase Analytics or RealTime DB

Tags: firebase, logging, syslog

I have a problem to understand my data in the Firebase Realtime Database,
it is not always clear and easy to navigate and query the data.

The database entries are not easily understood and interpreted. Adding more data to make the entries more clear will add to the data storage costs. 
Adding extra data for a certain duration, cannot be cleared out easily. It is also not visible when database read operations are performed. Dates are stored as an integers and cannot be interpreted easily. I have to use a bash command "date -r ", etc.

Clearly the database alone is not enough to debug flow of events,
and as the database grows, analysis of data will be harder.

**I have no record of the sequence of the events that describes the database entries.**

**Possible solutions:**

**(1) Use Realtime Database**

I create another Realtime Firebase "node" and log all the events in a human friendly way to this node". This way I have control over this data and can clear this at any time I wish, minimising the data "costs". The only problem I see with this is that I will have to periodically have to remember to clear this data. (Perhaps Firebase has some periodic scheduler to call some process). Or use some mobile clients to trigger the events...

**(2) Fabric**

My other option is to use Fabric's Answers, but after looking at the reporting of this data, it does not really suite my needs, no filtering and the details of the messages are not really as verbose as I have expected.

**(3) Firebase Analytics**

I am not sure about Firebase Analytics, I see no mechanism to clear events,
will this add to my costs? Will it be easy enough to filter / query logs
to analyse a certain sequence of events.

Typically I would like to see data something like this:

```
data_time_user_friendly,user_id,user_friendly_id,event_action,payload
```

**What is the best practice to have a remote syslog for analysing my data and flow of events.**

---

**Edited ....**

After some searching, I found there are numerous products that seem more suitable and are specifically developed for logging.

I did a quick comparison of some "free" products for system logging:

```
Papertrail         100 MB/month      7 days retention search 48 hours
Loggly             200 MB/day        7 days retention
Bugfender          100K lines/day    1 day  retention
Logz.io            1GB/day           3 days retention
```

This is just a quick comparison and have not evaluated any of the options.

Does Firebase have a solution for this or is it best to use one of the above mentioned products?

Comment: I have notices that the following:
Free Products
Authentication (except Phone Auth), Analytics, App Indexing, Dynamic Links, Invites, Remote Config, Cloud Messaging (FCM), Performance Monitoring, and Crash Reporting.
https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=1

Does this mean Analytics Storage is free?

Comment: Google Analytics for Firebase provides free and unlimited reporting of analytics events. If you want to perform custom analysis on the analytics event stream, you can export the events to BigQuery in realtime. BigQuery is a paid service, but there is a free tier.

Comment: A few things; *it is not always clear and easy to navigate and query the data* is probably true if when you first start working with Firebase. It was unclear to me when I first started 4 years ago coming from a strong SQL background. The concept of 'tables' doesn't exist in Firebase DB and data being *not visible* is related to how that data is stored and Firebase Rules. *Dates are stored as an integers and cannot be interpreted easily* is dependent on how the date is stored; for example; a node like:  timestamp: 20171105083300 is clear to me. Can the question be clarified?

Comment: I came across this:  bugfender.com seems to be more suitable to use.